# añadir campo de tipo texto normal (no cuadro de texto) a formulario en symfony

Tags: symfony

quiero mostrar una lista de nombres (que saco de una base de datos) en un formulario con su correspondiente boton de borrar y actualizar. Pero al añadir un campo al formulario de esta forma:`->add('nombre',null,array('data' => $gen["name"],'label' =>'nombre', 'attr' => array('class' => 'className')))`
me aparece como un cuadro de texto y yo lo que quiero es el texto sin mas, no se si me explico, no como un textbox, es decir no como un `<input type="text">`  sino mas bien como un `<label >First name:</label>`
Este es el codigo del controlador:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Genus;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AppBundle\Form\GenusFormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\AddressType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage"))
 */
   
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $genuses = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Genus')
    ->consulta(20);
   
    foreach ($genuses as $gen)
    {
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    //->setAction($this->generateUrl('app_lucky_number'))
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('homepage'))
    ->setMethod ("POST")
    ->add('nombre',null,array('data' => $gen["name"],'label' =>'nombre', 'attr' =>   array('class' => 'className')))
    ->add('id',HiddenType::class, ['data' => $gen["id"],])
    ->add('actualizar', SubmitType::class,array('label' => 'actualizar','attr' => array('class' => 'className')))
    ->add('borrar', SubmitType::class,array('label' => 'borrar','attr' => array('class' => 'className')))        
    ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $genus = $form->getData();
        $id=$genus["id"];
        if ($form->get('borrar')->isClicked())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $genuses = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Genus')
            ->borrar($id);
        }
       
        //return $this->render('genus/principal.html.twig',array('name'=>$name));
        return $this->render('genus/principal.html.twig',array('id'=>$id));
    }
    $formularios[]=$form->createView();
    }        
    return $this->render('genus/show.html.twig',['genuses'=>$formularios]);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Quieres que aparezca un listado con los campos de 'genus' para editarlos desde la propia lista?

Comment: si, exacto. Eso es lo que necesito.

Comment: Para eso symfony incluye un tipo de campo llamado CollectionType, con el que puedes editar varias entidades desde la misma página, mira la documentación y si tienes alguna duda comentanos: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: pero eso seria para añadir una coleccion de formularios. Lo de los formularios ya lo tengo resuelto, lo unico que quiero es añadir texto plano al formulario. Pero por lo que veo no tiene solucion facil.

Comment: he encontrado esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856109/symfony-add-text-in-generated-form  Donde pone que para añadir texto plano es necesario añadirlo en el template.

Comment: Deacuerdo, el texto que quieres mostrar no puede ser editado no? por lo tanto no te recomiendo que lo pongas en un formulario, ya que si luego por algún modo consiguen editar dicho texto y enviar el formulario, symfony cambiará el valor de la propiedad de ese objeto. Lo que te recomiendo es pasar dicho objeto directamente a la plantilla y mostrar esa propiedad.